# Displaying image in blackberry browser field

Tags: image, blackberry, browserfield

I have this html that comes from a web service and inside it there is an img tag, the problem is that when displaying the html content on a BrowserField, the images can´t be resolved, so they won't show.

Is there a way to enable the browserField to look up this images at their urls?

This is my code:

```
BrowserFieldConfig bfc = new BrowserFieldConfig();
bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_CARET);
bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);


BrowserField bf = new BrowserField(bfc);
bf.displayContent(m.getHtml(),"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "");
add(bf);
```

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the HTML source (with an `<img />`) that you say won't load?

Comment: Which version you are working?